# Can Integration constant be anything?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

When the question is to solve a given ODE (without initial value), can I assign any value to the constant $C$, in order to solve it, or is there a specific constant value that must be found?

In other words can two people assume different combination to the constant C to solve ODE, or one of them would be wrong?

Example: $$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{xdx}{x^2+1}$$ $$\ln(y)=\ln\sqrt{x^2+1}+C$$
So in order to solve it I assume $C=\ln(e^c)$, but why? Can a different person assume different value? or is this the only value in the world that must be assumed for $C$ in order to solve it?
Solution:$$y=C\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

Comment: Edits and improvements are welcome

Comment: There are some restrictions on $C$. For instance, it cannot be a banana.

Comment: We done that just to get rid off $\ln$ from the solution $\ln y=\ln(\sqrt{x^2+1})+C$. You have seen your self that by letting $C=\ln e^c$ we have reached such a simple form of the solution as $y=C\sqrt{x^2+1}$, which is simple and elegant. Now in the final solution, in place of $C$ you can put any value as long as it represents a constant.

Comment: lol =)) hahaha you funny

Comment: These transformations from one $C$ to the next are just convenience; you could keep the transformed form if you want. In fact it may be better to do that, because it may be that your transformation makes the $C$ no longer arbitrary. For example, if $C$ is an arbitrary real constant, then $e^C$ is no longer a completely arbitrary constant, it is an arbitrary *positive* constant.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Why not?  The derivative of a constant banana is still zero. 

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, lmao =)))

Comment: @KushalBhuyan, Ian, Oooh, I see, So I shouldn't stress out if my C is not exactly the same as the C of my neighbor. In other words the parameters of my C is not what's important, it's how I use it to simplify my ODE?

Comment: Welcome Jek. Notice than $ln(x)$ take all the values of $\mathbb R$ so with your choice you do not discard any possible value for your indefinite constant, furthermore it is clear that it is a convenient choice (another detail: the closed form of the answer is because the function logarithm is injective so $ln(A)=ln(B)\Rightarrow A=B$)

Comment: It is much better to think about this geometrically, all you are doing is integrating a vector-field (possibly time dependent). When you integrate a vector-field you get a family of curves tangent to your vector-field (called integral curves) and chosing an initial point amounts to choosing a point on the space where your vector-field is defined and taking the integral curve that passes through that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a differential equation problem consists of two parts: a *system of equations* and *boundary conditions*.

Suppose we're dealing with functions of time. The system of equations describes how quantities **change** over time. The boundary conditions—if they are provided—tell you about how quantities **take on specific values at specific times**. In this way, the boundary conditions constrain the space of solutions.

Here's a simple example from calculus: I tell you that $$y^\prime = 2x.$$ This is a system containing one equation. There are many solutions to this equation: $y(x) = x^2$, for example, or $y(x) = x^2 - 3$, or $y(x) = x^2 + 17$. Notice (by plugging in) that each of these different functions satisfies the differential equation. In general, for shorthand, we write that the set of solutions is just

$$y(x) = x^2 + C \qquad (\text{for any }C)$$
where each new value of $C$ gives you a different solution, and every solution to the equation can be expressed this way.

---

But in addition to providing the differential equation $y^\prime = 2x$, I might also give you a boundary condition such as $y(2) = 7$.

Now we must only consider solutions to the differential equation that satisfy this new constraint. In particular, out of the infinitely many possible solutions of the form $y(x) = x^2 + C$, only one of them satisfies the boundary condition— namely,

$$y_\star(x) = 2x + 3.$$

---

Differential equations may have many— even infinitely many — solutions. Some of these solutions will depend on a choice of constant. The general rule is that **any function you find which satisfies the differential equation is a valid solution.**

Boundary conditions impose additional constraints— if you have boundary conditions, the solution must satisfy not only the differential equation, but the boundary conditions at well.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation has a solution that is unique up to multiplication by the constant $C$. In your case $C$ must be in the range of $\ln e^{c}$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$ so $C$ can be any real number. This means you have an infinite set of solutions. If I pick something different, say my solution is $y=g(x)$ as long as there is some constant $C$ you can pick so $g(x)=C\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$ we're both okay; our functions are basically the same but mine is yours stretched or compressed vertically.

When you solve an ODE like this you're coming up with a *set* of solutions. In order to get a specific one you usually need an initial value for the function which will restrict your choice of $C$ to a single, distinct constant, e.g., $y(x_0)=y_0$ where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are just numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)